# NSValueTransformer in MonoMac

Tags: mono, monomac

I can't seem to see the [NSValueTransformer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class when developing a MonoMac application using MonoDevelop.  For instance, this simple code gives a compilation error:

```
public class MyTransformer : MonoMac.Foundation.NSValueTransformer
{
}
```

But I do see it added to this fork of the official MonoMac distribution:

https://github.com/baulig/monomac/commit/2c4e6d24e966bb795fb70624ea5bebce74f653fc

How come it isn't included by default?  How can include the commit from the above link in my distribution?  Or can I perform value transforms in IB without explicitly referencing this class/interface?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I merged all my changes upstream.  This is the corresponding commit from the official distribution:
https://github.com/mono/monomac/commit/2c4e6d24e966bb795fb70624ea5bebce74f653fc

Comment: Thanks for the info, and respect to you sir for all your great work. I should have mentioned that I'm using the latest Beta 3.0.1 that I installed last night from http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html.  I guess this pre-built package doesn't include these latest commits?

Comment: MonoMac is shipped as part of MonoDevelop, not Mono.  MonoDevelop 3.0.5, which was released a month ago, should have these changes.

Comment: @MartinBaulig It's not there in 3.0.5

Comment: Hmm, yeah.  It looks like MonoDevelop is shipping an older version of MonoMac.dll, no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSValueTransformer was added on August 8th, which possibly predates the most recent release?

I build monomac from source and I am using NSValueTransformer in my code.

This article should help you build from source and use that in your distribution:

[MonoMac from Source](http://cocoa-mono.org/archives/80/exploring-cocoa-with-monomac-and-c-chapter-1-%E2%80%93-getting-started-%E2%80%93-part-2/)